# Flutter: The getter isn't defined for the type

Tags: flutter, dart

I am stuck at page routing.

Here is the code from main.dart

```
import 'package: test/routes/router.gr.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/home_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          initialRoute: Router.homeScreenRoute,
          onGenerateRoute: Router.onGenerateRoute,
          navigatorKey: Router.navigatorKey,

        );
      }
    }
```

Here is the router.gr.dart file generated from auto-router.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:test/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:test/viewownprofile.dart';
import 'package:test/view_other_profile.dart';

abstract class Routes {
  static const homeScreenRoute = '/';
  static const viewownProfile = '/viewown-profile';
  static const viewotherProfile = '/viewother-profile';
  static const all = {
    homeScreenRoute,
    viewownProfile,
    viewotherProfile,
  };
}

class Router extends RouterBase {
  @override
  Set<String> get allRoutes => Routes.all;

  @Deprecated('call ExtendedNavigator.ofRouter<Router>() directly')
  static ExtendedNavigatorState get navigator =>
      ExtendedNavigator.ofRouter<Router>();

  @override
  Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case Routes.homeScreenRoute:
        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case Routes.viewownProfile:
        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (context) => ViewOwnProfile(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case Routes.viewotherProfile:
        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (context) => ViewOtherProfile(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      default:
        return unknownRoutePage(settings.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code for Homescreen.dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar (title: Text('Home')),
        body: Center(
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            elevation: 10.0,
            child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  'Welcome Home!',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0
                  ),
                )
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting error in main.dart file. Below is the error.

```
The getter 'homeScreenRoute' isn't defined for the type 'Router'.
Try importing the library that defines 'homeScreenRoute', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'homeScreenRoute'.
```

Similar error for **onGenerateRoute** and **navigatorKey**.

Comment: `initialRoute: Routes.homeScreenRoute`

Comment: @pskink how about onGenerateRoute and navigatorKey? Is there any detailed document for auto-route or something?

Comment: did you try `Routes.homeScreenRoute` instead of `Router.homeScreenRoute`?

Comment: @pskink error is gone when i changed it to Routes.homeScreenRoute but not sure this is the correct way to use Auto-Route.

Comment: if you are using that package read [this](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#setup-and-usage) first

Comment: @pskink i tried that link but still its on very high level i suppose. Also i just started learning Flutter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the newer version of flutter, it has a class already named "Router" so only you have to give a different name to your class "Routes".

and then user Routes.homeScreenRoute to your main.dart file.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It would be better if you give som example code.

Answer (score 1):

it's true,

In the newer version of flutter, it has a class already named "Router" so only you have to give a different name to your class "Router" in the router.gr.dart file.

You can change the class name from "Router" to => "RouterAuto"

Answer (score 1):

As you can see answers already given still i want to give little detailed code.

This is my working code prior to Flutter 2. As i haven't migrated to Flutter 2.

Rest all code will be the same only this file needs some modification.

**Router.dart**

```
import 'package:apppath/search.dart';
import 'package:apppath/settings.dart';
import 'package:apppath/login.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: [
    // initial route is named "/"
    MaterialRoute(page: AnimatedSplashScreen, initial: true),
    MaterialRoute(page: Search),
    MaterialRoute(page: Settings),
    MaterialRoute(page: Login),

  ],
)
class $Router {}
```

**MaterialRoute(page: Settings),** - This Search value is basically from the dart file.
My StatefulWidget name is **Settings** and same needs to add **MaterialRoute(page: Settings),**
e.g

```
class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
other codes
```

**How to use.**

```
ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
    Routes.settings,
);
```