# The getter 'health_and_safety_outlined' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, icons, getter

Codecanyon reject my flutter project by telling

Please fix the bug
"The getter 'health_and_safety_outlined' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'.

i run both android and ios but icon health_and_safety_outlined is showing

does anyone know what they telling?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/61832126/14351818?

Comment: have you found a solution ?